# How to add event on google calendar using calendar API using android?

Tags: android, calendar, google-api, google-calendar-api

Hi I am trying to create an event in **Google calendar** using Google calendar API in android.

I have created a sample project provided by  [Google](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse?repo=samples#hg/calendar-android-sample), and I followed the each steps and compiled the project successfully.

But in this Example of Google calendar, I can only create a calendar name to my Google calendar account, I can't create any event.

Is there any way to create an event in Google calendar? If so how can I do it?

Comment: Follow below link . <a>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43658751/add-events-to-calendar-programmatically?answertab=votes#tab-top</a>

Comment: Follow below link . <a>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43658751/add-events-to-calendar-programmatically?answertab=votes#tab-top</a>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After Searching for some time i have finally find the solution .the answer was in the google document it self just go through  [this link](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert#examples)

it shows how to create an event using google calender api.

Comment: hiii can u plz send me code or tell me how to add event in google calendar from or apps in background.i want to add event while i select one date from my customs made calendar.and then i can see that default evnet in google calendar in my login calendar

Comment: hiii can u plz tell me how to add event in google calendar without open the popup..i cant understand the doc. i completed the make api and add the key in google account.but dont understand how to add event tell me plz?

Comment: just download the source code in the question just go through the code

Comment: hey i copy the code for simple add event from above link but i want to add it in google calendr which i want to add static username and password in my apps.so how can it posible? if u r in any room then provide me the link so we can do the discussion about that plz?

Comment: static user name and password will not work first u should login using your g idz.then only u can add event

Comment: but i want to add event in username and password which is i added in aaps.so any other ways is there? my apps get the id of google paly login and then add the enent in that id.prob is there

Answer (score 6):

This is such a giant pain in the ass - but I finally got it working for creating events at least.

Download the most recent Google PHP API zip, and upload it to your includes folder on your webserver. Use Google API Console to set up an API client. Make sure you set your redirect url to be the same as your page's url - so it redirects to its self.

I've initially just set some variables for event details, you can make a form which shoves these in if you want.

Here's my code:

```
<?php
    $jobname = "BINGO";
    $joblocation = "Your mums house";
    $jobdescription = "An interview with a dog.";
    $startofjob = "2013-12-20T17:00:00.000+00:00"; //datetimes must be in this format
    $endofjob = "2013-12-20T18:00:00.000+00:00"; // YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.MMM+HH:MM
    //So that's year, month, day, the letter T, hours, minutes, seconds, miliseconds, + or -, timezoneoffset in hours and minutes



    include('google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php');
    include('google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_CalendarService.php');

    session_start();

    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName('doesntmatter-whateveryouwant');
    $client->setClientId('yourclientid');
    $client->setClientSecret('yourclientsecret');
    $client->setRedirectUri('yourredirecturl-setingoogleconsole');
    $client->setDeveloperKey('yourdeveloperkey');
    $cal = new Google_CalendarService($client);

    if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
      $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
      $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
      header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    }

    if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
      $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
    }

    if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
      $event = new Google_Event();
    $event->setSummary($jobname);
    $event->setDescription($jobdescription);
    $event->setLocation($joblocation);
    $start = new Google_EventDateTime();
    $start->setDateTime($startofjob);
    $event->setStart($start);
    $end = new Google_EventDateTime();
    $end->setDateTime($endofjob);
    $event->setEnd($end);

    $createdEvent = $cal->events->insert('YOURCALENDARID@GOOGLE.COM', $event);
    echo $createdEvent->id;


    $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    } else {
      $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
      print "<a class='login' href='$authUrl'>Connect Me!</a>";
    }
?>
```